# How to get data type of a value in F#

Tags: f#

Consider i have a function like `convert` and it can returns an `int` or throw an exception.

I need to check the datatype of this function?

something like:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
```

How can i do it in F#?

Comment: Did you do any research? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340517.aspx

Answer (score 2):

`typeof<'T>` returns the `Type` of a supplied type, while `a.GetType()` will tell you the `Type` of a particular object.  Finally, `a :? 'T` will tell you if a particular object is of a particular type `'T`.

Hence convert could be

```
let covert a =
    match box a with
    | :? int as i -> i
    | _ -> failwith "a is not an int"
```

Note you can only perform these runtime type tests on reference types, hence the need to box.